# Missing optional dependency 'tables'. Use pip or conda to install tables

Tags: python, h5py

```
import sys
#import datetime as dt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pylab import plt
plt.style.use('ggplot')
import matplotlib as mpl

mpl.rcParams['font.family'] = 'serif'

def load_h5(fn):
    h5 = pd.HDFStore(fn, 'r')
    data = h5['data']
    log_returns = h5['log_returns']

    h5.close()
    return data, log_returns


def save_h5(fn, data, log_returns):
    h5 = pd.HDFStore(fn, 'w')
    h5['data'] = data
    h5['log_returns'] = log_returns
    h5.close()

import os
from os.path import isfile, join

fn = join(os.getcwd(), 'stock.h5')
data, log_returns = load_h5(fn)
log_returns.head()
```

I wanted to read 'stock.h5' file which is place in the same folder and ran the above code. The jupyter notebook gave the error below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dp9bj.png)

I tried:

pip install --user tables

conda install --user tables

degrade pytables to 3.5.1

And none of them works

Comment: Is this a Pandas or a h5py issue/question? You tagged with h5py, but are using Pandas to access the file. (I'm not familiar with Pandas, so can't help. I do know Pandas has a dependency on PyTables aka tables.)

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same thing. The error tells you (unhelpfully) that the missing package is called `tables` when in fact, it's called `pytables`. Doing `conda install pytables` is all I needed to do to be able to read h5 files with pandas.

Answer (score 0):

I think [pd.to_hdf()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_hdf.html) and [pd.read_hdf()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_hdf.html) could simply realize the saving and loading hdf5 files' requirements without installing the tables package.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31182929)